# ComboBox "loses" info about its Items?

Tags: c#

So i add items to a ComboBox in a function if i display the Count of comboBox.Items.Count there it shows it correctly, all items are also added correctly and everything.

Then later i disable the comboBox if a checkBox is not checked and i enable it again if the checkBox is enabled. THis is the checkbox CheckedChanged event code:

```
if (checkBox.Checked)
{
    minCombo.Enabled = true;
    maxCombo.Enabled = true;
    minCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
    if (maxCombo.Items.Count > 1)
    {
        minCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
        maxCombo.SelectedIndex = maxCombo.Items.Count - 2;
    }
    else
    {
        minCombo.Text = "";
        maxCombo.Text = "";
    }
}
else
{
    minCombo.Text = "";
    minCombo.Enabled = false;
    maxCombo.Text = "";
    maxCombo.Enabled = false;
}
```

But here the Items in the comboBoxes are GONE and the Items.Count is 0 even tho the items are still there in the dropdown menu on the control if i click it also minCombo and maxCombo have the same items

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? Something else? If you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would really help a *lot*.

Comment: winforms cant really provide a complete program would take to much of my time i guess i will look for the solution myself if the description isnt enough

Comment: It's *absolutely* feasible to provide short but complete WinForms programs. Just because the WinForms designer produces large amounts of code doesn't mean you have to.